# How put quartile values on serval boxplots in one graph in r?

Tags: r, boxplot

I want to display quartile values of three boxplots, which exist on a single graph. Here is an example to show what I want.

```
a <- rnorm(10)
b <- rnorm(7)
c <- rnorm(9)
boxplot(a,b,c)
```

Then how to show the quartile values of each boxplot on my graph?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should examine the return value of `?boxplot` and use it like so `bp <- boxplot(a,b,c)$stats; text(col(bp), bp, round(bp, 1))`

Comment: Combine your three datasets in a single data.frame (using, for example, `df <- stack(list(a=a,b=b,c=c))`), and then use the code linked to by @rawr.

Comment: @rawr, how to shift the value of quartiles to left side of each boxplot?

Comment: @rwar,@Josh O'Brien, And how to add mean of each sequence onto each boxplot? Thanks!

Comment: @WhiteBig try `text(col(bp) - rep(c(.25, .5, .5, .5, .25), ncol(bp)), bp, round(bp, 1)); mm <- sapply(list(a, b, c), mean); segments(1:3 - .2, mm, 1:3 + .2, mm, col = 2); text(1:3, mm, round(mm, 1))`

Comment: I use the pos() and adj() manually adjusted it. Will try your method, thanks so much!